# Как изменить выходящий размер данных из геометрического шейдера?

Tags: opengl, шейдеры

По умолчанию выходящий размер данных из геометрического шейдера 1024 байта. Я нигде не смог найти упоминания о том как менять максимальный размер выходящих данных или хотя бы о том, что этот размер невозможно поменять. Буду очень признателен за ссылки на информацию.